# Jquery Fileupload replacing the browsed file bug?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-file-upload

Guys im using [Blueimp fileupload plugin](http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/)

And here's my problem, everything works fine, i can upload successfully, now when I noticed that when i browse a file, then i decided to replace that "already browsed file" with another file, and I press upload, the two files will be uploaded. Anyone experienced this too?

Do I have to paste the code? I jsut followed the tutorial from their site.

Answer (score -1):

You probably want to set the `autoUpload` option to `false`. By default, uploads are started automatically when adding files with `autoUpload: true`.